# Laplace's tidal equations

Tags: fluid-dynamics, resource-recommendations, geophysics, tidal-effect

Do you know where to find a clear, pedagogical derivation of [Laplace's tidal equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theory_of_tides) for the tidal elevation $\zeta$ and the velocities $u$ and $v$ of a fluid sheet located on a rigid body?

Answer (score 1):

Lamb treats this in detail in *Hydrodynamics*.  See https://archive.org/details/hydrodynamics00horarich